# How do I call field data from an associated table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In nodejs with mysql and sequelize, I render a page through a controller using the findAll function and include two assoicated table. I then render a view page. I loo through the table listing field data from the main table and want to add a pice of associated date from another table. Specifically I store the saleId from the table Sales in the table Project. When I list  the rows of Project, I would like to include the name in Sales that corresponds with the is in sales stored in projects foriegn key.

I will include the code below but the result is :
TypeError: E:\cjrfull\views\index.ejs:26
    24|                                 
    25|                                     <%= project.address %>, <%= project.csz %>

> > 26|                             Sales Rep: <%= project.sales.name %> 
> >         27|                             Project Manager: <%= project.supervisor.name %></small> -->
> >         28|                             
> >         29|

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile (E:\cjrfull\node_m

```
From app.js:
const sequelize = require('./util/database');
const Project = require('./models/project');
const Sales = require('./models/sales');
const Supervisor = require('./models/supervisor');

...
Project.belongsTo(Sales);
Sales.hasMany(Project);
Project.belongsTo(Supervisor);
Supervisor.hasMany(Project);

from model Project.js:
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    projectNo: Sequelize.STRING,
    owner1Fn: Sequelize.STRING,
    owner1Ln: Sequelize.STRING,
    owner2Fn: Sequelize.STRING,
    owner2Ln: Sequelize.STRING,
    address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    csz: Sequelize.STRING,
});

from model Sales.js:
const Sales = sequelize.define('sales', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

from Controller:
exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
    Project.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: Sales
            }],
            include: [{
                model: Supervisor
            }]
        })
        .then(projects => {
            res.render('index', {
                projs: projects,
                pageTitle: 'Index',
                path: '/'
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
from View file Index.ejs:
<% for (let project of projs) { %>
                            <a href="/project/<%= project.id %>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" style="background-color: darkgreen" style="border-color: darkgreen">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                    <h5 class="mb-1">
                                        <%= project.owner1Fn %>
                                            <%= project.owner1Ln %><span> & </span>
                                                <%= project.owner2Fn %>
                                                    <%= project.owner2Ln %>
                                    </h5>
                                    <small>Job: <%= project.id %>  Project: <%= project.projectNo %></small>
                                </div>
                                <p class="mb-1">
                                    <%= project.address %>, <span><%= project.csz %></p>
                            <small>Sales Rep: <%= project.sales.name %> </small><br>
                            <!-- <small>Project Manager: <%= project.supervisor.name %></small> -->
                            </a>
                            <br>
                        <% } %>
```

Comment: Let me know if the answer I posted works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you are including the associated models. You need to add them to the same array.

```
Project.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: Sales
            }, {
                model: Supervisor
            }]
        })
```

From the docs:

> A list of associations to eagerly load using a left join. Supported is either { include: [ Model1, Model2, ...]}